# YSOD When trying to open the login page - "No process is on the other end of the pipe"

Tags: sql-database, login

I have 12 different instances (test purpose only) using this same SQL Server.

All of the sudden, one of those (which was working fine until yesterday) started giving me this error **when I try to open the login page**. For the records only, it is brand new Sitecore 9.1 XP instance.

[image]

Initially, I thought it could be something with my SQL Server instance, but then I realize that **all the other Sitecore instances are working perfectly**.

If it can help, there it is the full stack trace:

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): No process is on the other end of the pipe]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)]
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +345
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +156
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +258
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +312
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +202
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +413
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +128
   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.DataProviderCommand..ctor(IDbCommand command, DataProviderTransaction transaction, Boolean openConnection) +107
   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<CreateCommand>b__0() +48
   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.Execute(Func`1 action, Action recover) +290
   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.<>c__DisplayClass29_0.<CreateReader>b__0() +30
   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.Execute(Func`1 action, Action recover) +290
   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.CreateReader(String sql, Object[] parameters) +281
   Sitecore.Data.Properties.SqlPropertyStore.GetStringValueCore(String name) +459
   Sitecore.Data.Properties.SqlPropertyStore.GetStringValue(String name) +73
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.IndexDatabasePropertyStore.Get(String key) +136
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexSummary.get_LastUpdatedTimestamp() +82
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.Strategies.BaseAsynchronousStrategy.LogStrategyInitialization(ISearchIndex index) +94
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.Strategies.BaseAsynchronousStrategy.Initialize(ISearchIndex searchIndex) +83
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.Strategies.IntervalAsynchronousStrategy.Initialize(ISearchIndex searchIndex) +18
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.TypeActionHelper.Call(Action`1 action, IEnumerable`1 instances) +197
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex.Initialize() +180
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrContentSearchManager.Initialize() +169
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrNetIntegration.DefaultSolrStartUp.Initialize() +923
   (Object , Object[] ) +71
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +469
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +161
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +767
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +580
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +165
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +353
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +341

[HttpException (0x80004005): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +523
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +107
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +688
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: I had exactly same error once when I forgot to change the number of CPU cores assigned to the VM. It wasn't able to run enough processes in parallel since the error. I don't know if that's a reason in your case though

Comment: Good point @MarekMusielak. I'm running an AWS machine m4.large, which is code for 2 CPU cores + 8GB RAM. Maybe I should upgrade that a little bit...

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by the "Maximum number of concurrent connections" setting in SQL Server being set too low for your situation.

From SQL Server Management Studio:

- Connect to your instance
- Right click your SQL instance in the Object Explorer and choose Properties.
- Select the Connections page and ensure you set the concurrent connections to an appropriate number, or zero for unlimited connections

[image]

If this is not the issue, it can be helpful when diagnosing an issue to check the SQL Server Error Logs and the Windows Event Logs for further information.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that @sitecorium, but it is already 0. Anyway, I'll keep my eye open if that happens again and will check for sure this number.

Comment: @HugoSantos No worries - remember to check the error logs, it could be something as simple as the user in that machine's connection string has an expired password or similar.